# Developer license expiration

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, modern-ui

I am developing my application using free developer license which I have got in VS.  This license have expiration date is one month after the date of issue.

I don't use Store and install app on our devices using power-shell script.

1. What will be with installed application after the license expire?
2. Is there any possibility to get developer license with expiration date more than 3 months?

Comment: 1. It stops working.  2. No.  Side-loading is an option, the up-front costs are very substantial.

Comment: Thanks. English is not my first language. Can you please explain what did you mean when you speak about up-front costs.

Comment: And another one question. If I created the package and install it with power shell script (without store) - is it side-loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer license you are using is designed for development and test purposes. It is not appropriate for production use. For production you will want to set the devices up for proper side-loading.

See [Try It Out: Sideload Windows Store Apps on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx) for how to enable side-loading on your systems.

If your Windows 8.1 Pro systems are on a domain then they don't need a separate key. You just need to enable them for side-loading. See [Windows 8.1 Update: Sideloading Enhancements](http://blogs.windows.com/itpro/2014/04/03/windows-8-1-update-sideloading-enhancements/)

The Windows RT systems can't join the domain so they'll need a key. If you're enrolled in a volume license program (see the Sideloading Enhancements link for which ones) you should be able to get side-loading keys from that. If not then you can buy an Enterprise Sideloading key through the [Open License program.](http://www.microsoft.com/indonesia/license/programs/open/)

See the [Windows Volume Licensing Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/4/3/9439A928-A0D1-44C2-A099-26A59AE0543B/Windows_8-1_Licensing_Guide.pdf) and [Sideloading Licensing Changes FAQ](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Enterprise%20Sideloading%20key%20%20Open%20License%20program&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IESR02)